# Import functions in a different file while using scrapyd

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I am building a crawler using scrapy and and run it on a remote machine running scrapyd. My spider is quite long and complex and so I put some functions in a different file `def.py`.

My project looks like this

```
./
|-- my_project
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- items.py
|   |-- pipelines.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   `-- spiders
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- spider.py
`-- scrapy.cfg
`-- def.py
```

I import my function in my spider with the following code

```
from def.py import get_questions
```

and use it within my spider.

It works perfectly in my local machine but if I send a crawl request to the scrapyd it is unable to find `def.py`. (`ImportError`)

I use `scrapyd-deploy` from pypi package `scrapyd-client`

```
scrapyd-deploy my_spider
```

Is the a way to include the `def.py` file or include the functions while sending a request to `scrapyd`?

I would prefer not to have a spider with hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: did you try putting your `def.py` inside your `spider` folder? you can still import it using `projectname.spiders.def import def.py`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it might be working locally is because you're probably running the commands from the same dir where your file with the function is.

`scrapyd-deploy` only deploys the files that are inside your project, so move your file with the util functions to inside your project and it'll get deployed to scrapyd.

You probably want to use a more descriptive name like `utils.py` instead of `def.py`, and drop the `.py` extension from the imports, to avoid conflicting syntax with the `def` keyword.